# View php 7.2 memory_limit for Apache 2 in the command line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, apache-http-server, php, memory-limit

Currently when I do the following command in the command line for ubunutu:

**php -i**

I get the php cli memory_limit, but how do I output the apache2 memory_limit in the command line? I know I can make a file and put info() to see it like that, but I want to see it in the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep` to find the line in the ini file -

```
grep memory_limit /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

Change the path appropriately. This assumes that any given script isn't changing it at run time, etc.